# Python File reading: How to exclude a specific subdirectory and the other way round

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I have an image reading function which reads all files of a directory (including the files of sub(sub...)directory) and stores them in a list. The parameter 'root' is the starting path location (root = "path/to/dir").

```
def load_images_from_folder(root):
    images = []
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for name in files:
            img = cv.imread(os.path.join(path, name), 0)
            if img is not None:
                images.append(img)
    return images
```

Inside of the root directory there are directories which each CAN have directories from 01 to 06. I want to first read all images which are located in 01-05 and store them in a different variable than the images located in 06. I have read something about excluding directories in find . command but did not find anything specific for this matter.

Comment: Can you not parse the path used to open the file to decide which variable to store the images in?  A simple version:  `if "06/" in path:`

Comment: I can but is it still possible to keep it with one function for first reading the images 01-05 and second read 06 only? Or do you think I should use two different functions?

Comment: well now that I am awake I can clearly see that it seems to be a trivial question. Maybe your hint was the only thing I needed. thanks for your answer @RufusVS
I will post my answer in a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got so far, there might be a better solution but you can tell me.

```
def load_images_from_folder(root):
    images_real = []
    images_spoof = []
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for name in files:
            img = cv.imread(os.path.join(path, name), 0)
            if img is not None:
                if "06/" in path:
                    images_real.append(img)
                else:
                    images_spoof.append(img)
    return images_real, images_spoof
```